# Maximum update depth exceeded. React useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting the following error with the component below. The weird thing is that it is only happening when I change something in in the file (for example changing a default prop) and save something in the file. I need to rely on the props kicking off a re-render since the list of items is being updated by a filter.

> Blockquote
>   This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

Here is the component code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

import Button from '../Button';

const nsBase = 'component';

const ns = `${ nsBase }-content-feed`;

const ContentFeed = (props) => {
  const {
    showAllItems,
    items,
    nextVisibleAmount,
    ItemView,
    loadButton
  } = props;

  let {
    initialVisibleAmount
  } = props;

  const {
    label
  } = loadButton;

  // if showAllItems display all items in items array
  if (showAllItems) {
    initialVisibleAmount = items.length;
  }

  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(initialVisibleAmount);
  const [visibleItems, setvisibleItems] = useState([...items]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setvisibleItems([...props.items]);

    if (props.items.length < initialVisibleAmount) {
      setVisible(props.items.length);
    } else {
      setVisible(initialVisibleAmount);
    }
  }, [props, initialVisibleAmount]);


  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    setVisible((prevState) => {
      return (prevState + nextVisibleAmount);
    });
  };

  const rootClassnames = classNames({
    [`${ ns }`]: true
  });

  return (
    <div className={rootClassnames}>
      {visibleItems.slice(0, visible).map((item, index) => {
        return <ItemView key={item.id} article={item} index={index} />;
      })}
      {(visible < visibleItems.length) && (
        <div className={`${ ns }__load-more`}>
          <Button onClick={handleLoadMore}><h4>{label}</h4></Button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ContentFeed;

ContentFeed.defaultProps = {
  showAllItems: false,
  items: [],
  initialVisibleAmount: 3,
  nextVisibleAmount: 3,
  ItemView: () => {
    return <div>Item View Default</div>;
  },
  loadButton: {
    label: 'More'
  }
};
```

Comment: You extract your props to constants, but then you go back to using `props.` values in your setters... I would stick to your constants to clarify your code and make your dependencies clearer. That might clear up the code enough to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add some checks in the use Effect hooks. As the `useEffect` first line always updating the state and it will result in an infinte loop. Any change in state will execute the `useEffect` hook as it is dependent on `props, initialVisibleAmoun`.

Try something like this.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if(props.items !== visibleItems) {
            setvisibleItems([...props.items]);
        }

        if(props.items.length !== visible) {
            if (props.items.length < initialVisibleAmount) {
                setVisible(props.items.length);
            } else {
                setVisible(initialVisibleAmount);
            }
        }

    }, [props, initialVisibleAmount]);
```